# Integration similaring to Fourier transform of Gaussian function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, transformation

I would like to calculate the integral:

$$\int^{\infty}_{0}x\cdot \exp(-x^2)\cdot \exp(-ikx)dx$$

Are there some tricks to solve it?

Many thanks.

Comment: The lower bound of integration being $0$ it is not easy to treat it with Fourier transform. But do you know Fourier Transforms ? Is so, the formula given by @Igor Rivinlet appears (after replacing$i^2$ by $-1$) obtainable by means of F. T., using Heaviside function and the preservation of the scalar product by F.T.

Answer (score 0):

You can complete the square in the exponent, and get an answer in terms of the Dawson function:

$$\frac{1}{4} \left(2-\sqrt{\pi } i k e^{\frac{i^2 k^2}{4}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{i
   k}{2}\right)\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
  \int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x^2}e^{-ikx}dx
   & = -\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ikx}\frac{d}{dx}e^{-x^2}dx \\
   & = -\left.\frac{1}{2}e^{-ikx}e^{-x^2}\right|_{0}^{\infty}-\frac{ik}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}e^{-ikx}dx \\
   & = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{ik}{4}\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}e^{-ikx}dx
\end{align}
So the problem reduces to the Fourier transform of a Gaussian.